# PermissionError no13 on installing steem library

Tags: python, permissions

I'm trying to install steem library on Ubuntu 16.04 using VMplayer and Python 3.5
Getting following error on running pip3 install steem:

```
       Exception:
      Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/orion/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
      packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
      status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/orion/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
 prefix=options.prefix_path,
File "/home/orion/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", 
line 784, in install
 **kwargs
 File "/home/orion/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
 packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
File "/home/orion/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
   packages/pip/req/req_install.py", 
line 1064, in move_wheel_files
isolated=self.isolated,
 File "/home/orion/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 
345, 
   in move_wheel_files
clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
File "/home/orion/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 323, in clobber
shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile)
 File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 115, in copyfile
with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
 PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-
 packages/appdirs.py'
```

Comment: Did you run the command with `sudo`?

Comment: oh thanks, its working now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the `pip3 install` command as sudo to avoid running into any permissions issues: `sudo pip3 install [PACKAGE]`